# make an input text into read only when one value is selected from drop down list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have one select box there in that options are,

- none
- current
- future

if you select 'NONE' the all text box should be editable.
if you select 'current' the `class="current"` those text box should be editable and remaining should be only readonly.
similarly same like to future also. When i select future the future text boxes should be editable and remaining should be readonly

```js
$('#cognizant').change(function(){
    if(this.value == ""){
        $('.current').prop('readonly',true);
     } else{
      $('.current').prop('readonly',false);
   }
 }).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="curator">
  <tbody id="tableToModify">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="cognizant" class="discount-type" >
            <option value="">none</option>
            <option value="1">current</option>
            <option value="2">future</option>
            
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
<input type="text"   id="clientbi" class="current"/>
<input type="text"   id="cognizantbi" class="current"/>
<input type="text"  id="futurevsm" class="future" />
 <input type="text"  id="futuresymbols" class="future" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change your javascript code only.

We need to use jQuery's `change()` function ([documentation](https://api.jquery.com/change/)) and then validate the selected option.

The final code:

```
$('#cognizant').change(function(){

  var value = $(this).val();

  if(value == ''){
    // NONE
    $('#curator input[type="text"]').removeAttr('readonly');
  }
  else if(value == '1'){
    // CURRENT
    $('#curator input[type="text"]').attr('readonly', true);
    $('#curator .current').removeAttr('readonly');
  }
  else if(value == '2'){
    // FUTURE
    $('#curator input[type="text"]').attr('readonly', true);
    $('#curator .future').removeAttr('readonly');
  }

});
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/x5fdLqff/4/

Comment: thank you for the answer..but in that when you are selecting none then you are enter some data and then you select current still that data is there in the text boxes..how to remove that text when you are selecting different options

Comment: is it possible for radio buttons

Comment: If you need empty fields, use the empty() function. For example: $('#curator input[type="text"]').attr('readonly', true).empty();

Comment: thank you,i added that empty() but its not effecting

Comment: Try .val("") instead of empty()

Comment: same thing i have to do for radio button also..that is current..then how to do readonly then

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#cognizant').change(function(){
    switch(this.value) {
    case "":
        $('.current').prop('readonly',false);
      $('.future').prop('readonly',false);
    break;
    case "1":
        $('.current').prop('readonly',false);
      $('.future').prop('readonly',true);
    break;
    case "2":
        $('.current').prop('readonly',true);
      $('.future').prop('readonly',false);
    break;
  }
 }).change();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <table id="curator">
      <tbody id="tableToModify">
        <tr>
            <td>
              <select id="cognizant" class="discount-type" >
                <option value="">none</option>
                <option value="current">current</option>
                <option value="future">future</option>

              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
    <input type="text"   id="clientbi" class="current myinputs"/>
    <input type="text"   id="cognizantbi" class="current myinputs"/>
    <input type="text"  id="futurevsm" class="future myinputs" />
     <input type="text"  id="futuresymbols" class="future myinputs" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <script>
    $('#cognizant').change(function(){
        var type = $("#cognizant").val();
      $( ".myinputs" ).each(function( index ) {
        $( this ).prop('readonly', false);
      });
      if(type != ""){
        $("."+type).each(function( index ) {
          $( this ).prop('readonly', true);
        });
      }
  });
</script>
```

I have change option value in select box and made little change in javascript code.

hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, with a small change in the html. You add a class name of 'none' to all the input fields, which is the same as option 1.

```
<table id="curator">
  <tbody id="tableToModify">
    <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="cognizant" class="discount-type" >
            <option value="">none</option>
            <option value="1">current</option>
            <option value="2">future</option>

          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="text"   id="clientbi" class="current none"/>
           <input type="text"   id="cognizantbi" class="current none"/>
           <input type="text"  id="futurevsm" class="future none" />
           <input type="text"  id="futuresymbols" class="future none" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Then the jQuery to be like this. Comments explain approach.

```
$(function(){

    $('#cognizant').on("change", function() {
        //Set all text boxes to readonly
        $("input[type='text']").prop("readonly", true);

        //Select the option text, based on its value.
        var text = $("#cognizant option[value='"+$(this).val()+"']").text();

        //Set the property readonly to false on the selected class. 
        $("."+text).prop('readonly', false);
   }).trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer..but in that when you are selecting none then you are enter some data and then you select current still that data is there in the text boxes..how to remove that text when you are selecting different options..is it possible for radio buttons...i have in current type is radio is also there...thanks

Comment: @RaviKumar Yes its possible to clear out the data for the textboxes, just add .val("") to the end of the code where its setting the prop readonly to true. i.e. $("input[type='text']").prop("readonly", true).val("");